# How to make the 'assign_public_ip_on_launch' option True in a subnet - Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have created a subnet within a VPC. The instance launched within the Subnet is not getting the auto-ip since the `assign_public_ip_on_launch` attribute of the subnet if `False`.

I did try to change the attribute to `True` and get my work done but it seems like it is write protected and not able to change it.

Is there any other way to do this using the Network Interface or anything else?

Here is the error I get when I try to change the attribute:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launch.py", line 20, in <module>
    subnet.map_public_ip_on_launch = True
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
subnet.meta.client.modify_subnet_attribute(SubnetId=subnet.id, MapPublicIpOnLaunch={"Value": True})
```

There is an outstanding issue in Boto3 to make this `subnet.map_public_ip_on_launch = True`

See [Boto3 Issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/276)

Answer (score 1):

`subnet.map_public_ip_on_launch` gives you the current value of the `map_public_ip_on_launch` attribute, you can't dynamically modify its value through it.

You should instead use the `EC2.client.modify_subnet_attribute(**kwargs)` [method](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_subnet_attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Even today (using boto3), auto-assign IP for Ipv4 and Ipv6 cannot be set in one command.

I set the values step by step:

```
# auto assign IPs (Ipv4, Ipv6)
ec2_client.modify_subnet_attribute(
    SubnetId=subnet.id,
    MapPublicIpOnLaunch={'Value': True},
)
ec2_client.modify_subnet_attribute(
    SubnetId=subnet.id,
    AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation={'Value': True},
)
```